# compile-time conditional member function call in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a template class for which certain member functions only make sense if the template parameters satisfy certain conditions. Using, for instance, `std::enable_if<>` I can define them only for these cases, but how can I call them conditionally? Here is a brief example

```
template<class T> class A
{
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type a_member();
   void another_member()
   {
     a_member(); // how to restrict this to allowed cases only?
   }
};
```

Comment: Do you want to remove them at compile time, error at compile time, or know at runtime?

Comment: How about providing an empty a_member overload for the rest of the types(not floating points).

Comment: @Linuxios just not call them at run time not present at compile time for this type.

Comment: @mfontanini can you make my example work with this?

Comment: Joe's answer is exactly what I meant :D.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you can't use SFINAE like that - the template type parameter needs to be on the function, not the class.

A full solution looks like this:

```
template<class T> class A
{
private:
   template <class S>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<S>::value>::type a_member() {
       std::cout << "Doing something";
   }

   template <class S>
   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<S>::value>::type a_member() {
       //doing nothing
   }

public:
   void another_member()
   {
     a_member<T>();
   }
};


int main() {
    A<int> AInt;
    AInt.another_member();//doesn't print anything

    A<float> AFloat;
    AFloat.another_member();//prints "Doing something"
}
```

Comment: +1 great! I tried that, but without the additional template over S, which is critical to avoid function overload.

Comment: The extra template parameter isn't to avoid ambiguous overloads. SFINAE works only on function templates, not class templates so you need to make those functions templates.

Comment: this is semantics. In order to use SFINAE, one needs different function signatures and an ambiguous overload cannot give that (my compiler (gcc/4.7.0) complains about overload).

Comment: @Walter: It's not semantics - SFINAE only works on template functions. If you resolve the overload ambiguity by giving two non-template functions different argument lists, it still won't work.

Comment: It would be nice to complete this answer with the fact that there is a  proposition to the next C++ standard (from D language designers) that add the famous static if that would be far far more elegant than enable if.

Answer (score 1):

## WARNING: This is a complete, terrible hack that I have not tried that may never work.

Try adding this to the class declaration:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>, int*>::type a_enabled_p() { return 0;};
void another()
{
  if((a_enabled_p()+1)==1)
  {
    //Not enabled
  }
  else if((a_enabled_p()+1)==sizeof(int))
  {
    //Is enabled
  }
}
```

Here's why this horror might work. If they are floating point, the return value of the predicate is an `int*`. If they are, there is no typedef, and it defaults to `int` (I hope). When you add 1 to an `int*`, you are really adding `sizeof(int)`. Adding 1 to an int increments by one. That means that by checking the value of adding one, we know.

Note: Don't use this. It was fun to come up with, but the above answer is MUCH, MUCH

## MUCH

Better. Don't use this. Please.

Comment: this is a run-time version and will not compile (your "not enabled" code is only not called, but still enabled).

Comment: @Walter: I never said it would work, but why? How? This is the first time I've even seen `std::enable_if`, so please enlighten me.